# Can't figure out how to use "i" in a For loop as an integer

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use "i" in the FOR loop as an index. Specifically to use something like "var sampleCell = 3 + i;

If it helps, i've spent 3 hours Googling to try to find the answer. I have experience with C, but it doesn't translate over very well, at least not for me. I've only just started coding with scripts.

```
function AutoManager() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
var sampleRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 6, numRows, 1);
var sampleData = sampleRange.getValues(); 
var statusRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1); 
var statusData = statusRange.getValues(); 

for (i in sampleData) {
  var sample = sampleData[i];
  var status = statusData[i];
  var sampleCell = 3;
  var cell = sheet.getRange(sampleCell,1);

  if((sample > 0) && (status < 1)) {
     cell.setValue(1);
  }    
}

MailApp.sendEmail("EMAIL", "TEST", "Hello");
}
```

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with the erroneous state of this question.

Comment: Fix the formatting please. Then people will help you.

Comment: Okay, i'll try. Sorry.

Comment: look up how to iterate an array in Javascript, dont use for (i in...)

Comment: Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript, take a look at the Mozilla Documentation [for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).  Take into account [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a two-dimensional array of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did not review all your code but you should definitely have a look at the mozilla documentation as ocordova sugested.
Anyway you should not use `for (var i in stuff)`structure where `stuff`is an `Array`.
The `var i in` structure should be reserved to `Object`.
Prefer to use `for (var i = 0; i<stuff.length; i++)` structure (I know it require some more caracters to write but it's better this way).
Otherwise if you still want to use `for (var i in stuff)` (please don't) you'll need to change your `3 + i;` expression to `3 + Number(i)` as in this case `i` is not really a number and adding a number with something that's not really a number is like adding text so `3+1 != 4` but `3+1 == 31`